# Reading data from tab separated xls file

Tags: c#, excel, xls, csv

I have a file with `.xls` extension which is actually having data separated by tab spaces i.e,
when I right click and open the file in NotePad I can see all the data in plain text separated by tab spaces

I am using the following connection string to read data from the file

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\abc.xls;Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=NO;IMEX=1;FMT=TabDelimiter;\";
```

it works for other files which are saved as .xls in Microsoft excel, but I get the following exception when I try with the above file

```
"External table is not in the expected format."
```

how should I read data from such a file in C#?

Comment: If it's a tab separated file, it is NOT an Excel file, even if it is associated with Excel in the OS and if Excel is able to open it. 
Just treat the file as any .txt tab separated file.

Comment: check this link http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile

Comment: @iDevlop i used this following connection string `Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=c:\txtFilesFolder\;
Extended Properties="text;HDR=NO;FMT=Delimited";` and this is not working for my file which is having .xls as extension, when i change the extension to .txt is reading all the data in one column only i.e, it is not considering tab as separator...also my file has some junk text in the first 6 rows so i gave HDR=NO in the above connection string

Answer (score 0):

The xls extension is just confusing things - you file has nothing to do with Excel.  Treat the file as the normal tab delimited file.  Loop past the first 6 rows since they contain "junk".

You can use the TextFieldParser class for this.

Microsoft has sample code and details at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser(v=vs.100).aspx